# Module 'device_info' not found

Tags: xcode, flutter

Getting Module 'device_info' not found Error While Creating Archive For Apple
I have Tried Every thing on StackOverflow and Also From Github.com
But Nothing Work

What I have Tried

1. Remove Pod And Install it again.
2. Clean Flutter Many times.
3. Also Copy Paste POD File From another Flutter Project But Nothing Works
4. Search On Internet From Morning But Noting Works.
5. I am Using Mac Big Sur and Xcode Version 13.1

Below I share my POD File

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Comment: my issue solved by opening workspace in xcode

Comment: @PragnaBhatt can you add some more details as how the problem solved?

Answer (score 3):

Open the ios project from `Runner.xcworkspace` not from `Runner.xcodeproj`.
Make sure that you select a real device not a simulator before starting the build.

Answer (score 0):

I have same error.
But I tried (Physical Device -> My own phone (iphone xs)) it works.
I think "device_info package" get device unique id. But ios simulators don't have unique id like imei.

Answer: Try Real Device